# how to access a function/ class in a Databricks repo from a Databricks workspace notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, databricks

I have a Databricks notebook in `/Repos/abc@work-email.com/repo-name/library'` that defines all the re-usable functions

```
class library():

    def summary_test(self):

        print('this is a test')
```

I can call this Databricks library from another Databricks Notebook in the same repo `/Repos/abc@work-email.com/repo-name/test_folder` without any problem.

```
%run ..//repo-name/library/library

# claim the class

library=library()

# run the function "summary_test" 

library.summary_test()
```

However, if there is another Databricks user creating his/her own Databricks notebook in his/her workspace `/Users/xyz@work-email.com/personal-folder`, how can this coworker call this library?

I know he/she can go to the same repo and create a branch and a new file to call this function. But I am more curious how this coworker can call this library from his/her personal workspace files.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Users can load the library the same way, but using the absolute path:

```
%run /Repos/abc@work-email.com/repo-name/library
```

Comment: Let me try tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: So i just tried it from the coworker's workspace to import the library using "%run /Repos/abc@work-email.com/repo-name/library" and it will say `Notebook not found:`

Comment: Check permissions on the your repository